# string matching and Text::Match::FastAlternatives

Tags: regex, performance, perl

I need to find all occurrences of lots short strings among lots of long strings in Perl. Just like

```
my $count = () = $bigstr =~ /$smallstr/g
```

Since regexs take a lot of time, I went into string matching algorithms and found the Perl module [`Text::Match::FastAlternatives`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Match::FastAlternatives). On the documentation it only says this module can be used to find whether or not a string is found inside another one. But is there a way of counting all the occurrences with `Text::Match::FastAlternatives`? Really hope so. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: What kind of short strings are you looking for? Please describe exactly what are these short strings and what was your regex approach.

Comment: My short strings are 6 to 10 characters in length and my approach was as mentioned earlier: my $count = () = $bigstr =~ /$smallstr/g. But I need to speed it up, more than using study. I need he speed of Text::Match::FastAlternatives. Is there a way? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

When you must reparse the regular expressions each time, yes that takes time.

I would advise [`Benchmarking`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html) different solutions, but one way to speed things up is to cache all the strings you intend to match against in anonymous subroutines.

Something like the following pseudo code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @short_strings = (...);

my @long_strings = (...);

my @match_subs = map {
    my $code = "sub { return scalar(() = shift =~ /\Q$_\E/g }";
    my $sub = eval $code;
    die "Unable to cache sub $code: $@" if $@;
    $sub
} @short_strings;

for my $data (@long_strings) {
    my $count;
    $count += $_->($data) for @match_subs;
    print $count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Miller! I'll try it and let you (and everybody else) know.

Comment: Yes it did, @Miller! Compiling the short strings + joining all long sequences into a giant one + using _study_ on them before the search gave a 10-fold speedup. But mostly because of the compiling. Thanks again!!

Comment: Hey guys, and what if I need to store the value in $-[0] after every match? What must be changed in `"sub { return scalar(() = shift =~ /\Q$_\E/g }"`? thanks again